# Performing efficient batch inserts after batch inserts using Ecto.Multi

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a transactional batch inserts where previous batch insert results will be used in another batch insert. My code below already works and just want to ask if there are part of the code to be improved.

```
      Multi.new()
      |> Multi.insert(:template, ChecklistTemplate.changeset(%ChecklistTemplate{}, attrs))
      |> Multi.merge(fn _ ->
        items = Map.get(attrs, "items")

        items
         |> Enum.with_index()
         |> Enum.reduce(Multi.new, fn {item, idx}, multi ->
          Multi.insert(multi, {:item, idx}, ChecklistItem.changeset(%ChecklistItem{}, item))
         end)

      end)
      |> Multi.merge(fn result ->
        template = Map.get(result, :template)
        max = length(attrs["items"]) - 1

        0..max
        |> Enum.reduce(Multi.new, fn id, multi ->
          item = Map.get(result, {:item, id})
          changeset = %Checklist{template_id: template.id, item_id: item.id}
          Multi.insert(multi, {:joined, id}, changeset)
        end)
      end)
      |> Repo.transaction()
```

I have sample data below:

```
%{
  "items" => [%{"name" => "National ID"}, %{"name" => "Postal ID"}],
  "name" => "Default"
}
```